# How to remove selected text from Logstash "message" field

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-configuration

Below is the sample "message" field which i am getting through logstash.

```
181 <14>1 2016-07-21T19:09:43.538674+00:00 loggregator 6eca5b5d-65cb-4190-ab35-64ec79ad1c1f [App/1] - -    SecurityFilterAutoConfiguration#securityFilterChainRegistration did not match
```

In this "message" field , i don't want `loggregator 6eca5b5d-65cb-4190-ab35-64ec79ad1c1f` , because it **decreases the readability** of the message.

How I can remove **this part** from the message field?

I saw the [removeField](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-drop.html#plugins-filters-drop-remove_field) filter configuration, but it seems removeField will remove the **entire** "message" field.

Any help/route to docs will be appreciated.

Comment: Check out the mutate filter, specifically replace field. And the gsub filter.

Comment: please update the question with your filter configuration so we can see what the best way for you to achieve that would be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mutate filter with gsub is the way, try it with:

```
  mutate {
    gsub => [
      "message", "loggregator [a-zA-Z0-9._-]+", ""
    ]
  }
```

Comment: Thanks  @baudsp, This is what I was looking for :-)